# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Identity for Single Page React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asp.net-core

Preface:

- I currently have a React Application running on Node.js for my frontend.
- I am also using ASP.NET Core 6.0 as the backend server.
- Finally, I am using MS SQL SERVER as my database engine.

For **user authentication**, I am currently using Google Firebase implemented on the React frontend. When a user signs up, the data is sent to the backend server via an API request and then the user is inserted into the database.

This process is because I would like to use a relational database with the application. I understand Firebase is using NoSQL. This is why I am also saving the user in a relational database on top of the Firebase database.

So:

1. User Signs up on React frontend hosted on Node.js server
2. Firebase creates user and posts it to their service
3. An API request is sent from the React frontend to the ASP.NET 6.0 backend with user information
4. The ASP.NET 6.0 backend saves the user in the relational database (MS SQL SERVER)

Something to consider: I do not need Firebase to authenticate users. I needed to skip a few steps in developing a Web App, so I used Firebase as a shortcut to handle basic frontend authentication. This will most likely be completely removed.

**Here is/are my question(s):**
Is what I am doing a good practice? Or should I configure ASP.NET Identity instead for my needs.

If ASP.NET Identity is the way to go, I assume it is as simple as passing Sign Up information via API requests from the frontend to the backend where the Identity is handled?

As these are separate applications (React frontend / ASP.NET Core 6.0), I have not found much information for best practices for User Authentication. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.